# Unite CGRects from Array

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to unite the CGRect info from the elements in an array that I receive back from this function. How should I go about taking only the `CGRect` objects out of the `[UITextSelectionRect] struct` it returns. Then looping over them and unioning them. What is the best way to do this?

```
let test = myTextView.selectionRects(for: paragraph.first!.range)
```

Comment: What does "uniting" mean?

Comment: @Alexander https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1455837-union

Comment: "uniting" != "unioning", please edit your question so people know what you're talking about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by “uniting them”.

`CGRect` has a `union` method:

```
let union = rect1.union(rect2)
```

This returns a `CGRect` that tightly encloses both `rect1` and `rect2`:

[image: union of two CGRect]

The union (the shaded green rectangle) encloses both of the input rectangles, but includes area outside of either input rectangles.

So you could apply this union operation to an array of `CGRect` like this:

```
let test = myTextView.selectionRects(for: paragraph.first!.range)
    .reduce(CGRect.null) { $0.union($1.rect) }
```

That will give you a `CGRect` that tightly encloses all of the selected text, but in general also encloses area that is not selected.

**If you want a shape that exactly encloses the input rectangles and does not enclose any area outside of the input rectangles**, then you want what is called the “contour” of the (geometric) union of the input rectangles. This contour is not, in general, a rectangle, so you have to represent it using a `CGPath` instead of using a `CGRect`.

Computing the contour of a set of rectangles is a much harder problem. Fortunately, I already solved it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48142437/77567).

Comment: Hi Rob! That is what I am wanting. I just tried it and am getting an error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" it's underling the union part. How should I fix this?

Comment: I have corrected my answer. The array returned by `selectionRects` is `[UITextSelectionRect]`, not `[CGRect]`.